# Flutter RiverPod - how to have two different widgets draw data from same FutureProvider?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have a complex multi panel display where each panel is a distinct widget and the data for each widget is sourced from a RiverPod Future provider.

Two of these widgets will use data from the same RiverPod Future provider, like...

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int? aHabitId = _getHabitId();
    final anEditFuture = ref.watch(findHabitOnlyProvider(aHabitId));
    return anEditFuture.when(
      data: (data) => _buildView(data!),
      error: (e, st) => Center(
        child: Text(e.toString()),
      ),
      loading: () => const Center(
          child: SizedBox(
              width: 50.0, height: 50.0, child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
    );
  }
```

If I include this code block in each distinct widget, will the Future Provider be called separately for each widget?  How can I structure this so that the the Future provider is only called once, and the data is made availble to both widgets?

Comment: As long as aHabitId has a consistent == (which int? does), you'll be looking at the same provider, so yes, they'll share the one cached state.  If the id changes, of course that'll be a new provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FutureProvider` will only be called once and the result will be cached. Therefore, repeatedly listening to this provider will return a cached value.

Of course, if your `aHabitId` argument is the same.